# Push all zero values to the end - Ruby on Rails (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table `vehicles` that `has_one` `vehicle_size`. The `VehicleSize` model has a column in the table `size`, a **String**. Here are examples of a `size` value: `12ft, 19ft, EV`. The goal is to sort `vehicles` based on the size from the `vehicle_sizes` table.

Here is my current solution:

```
  def order_by_size(resources)
    return resources unless context.params[:by_size] == 'asc' || context.params[:by_size] == 'desc'

    if context.params[:by_size] == 'desc'
      resources.joins(:vehicle_size).group('vehicle_sizes.size').order('vehicle_sizes.size DESC')
    else
      resources.joins(:vehicle_size).group('vehicle_sizes.size').order('vehicle_sizes.size ASC')
    end
  end
```

The solution above performs sorting. First, however, I need to push all `zero` values to the end regardless if the order is `desc` or `asc` (* zero means `EV` or any other string without numbers).

I tried to sort records with `.sort { ... }`, but it returns an `array` instead of `active relation`, with is necessary for me.

Solution where I get an `array` with `sort`:

```
  def order_by_size(resources)
    return resources unless context.params[:by_size] == 'asc' || context.params[:by_size] == 'desc'

    if context.params[:by_size] == 'desc'
      resources.joins(:vehicle_size).group('vehicle_sizes.size').sort do |x, y|
        if x.vehicle_size.size.to_i.zero?
          1
        elsif y.vehicle_size.size.to_i.zero?
          -1
        else
          y.vehicle_size.size.to_i <=> x.vehicle_size.size.to_i
        end
      end
    else
      resources.joins(:vehicle_size).group('vehicle_sizes.size').sort do |x, y|
        if x.vehicle_size.size.to_i.zero?
          1
        elsif y.vehicle_size.size.to_i.zero?
          -1
        else
          x.vehicle_size.size.to_i <=> y.vehicle_size.size.to_i
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

How can I modify my first or second solution to return an `active relation` where all `String` (zeros) will be pushed to the end regardless of sorting? Am I missing something here?

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VehicleSize.order(Arel.sql("size = 'EV', size"))
```

or

```
VehicleSize.order(Arel.sql("size = 'EV', size desc"))
```

This way records with size = EV will be last, but others will be sorted as you need

Result will be relation

If you need specify table name, you can use `vehicle_sizes.size` instead of `size`

If you have few values without number (EV and ED here) you can do something like this to avoid hardcode

```
zero_array = %w[EV ED]

VehicleSize.order(
  VehicleSize.sanitize_sql_for_order([Arel.sql("size IN (?), size DESC"), zero_array])
)
```

Comment: The problem here is that the `size` column is a String. If I use the `ruby` sort here, I will do something like this `vehicle_size.size.to_i`, which converts `EV` to `0`. In other words, all string values like `EV` have to be converted to an integer value first. Here is an example of an output: `22ft, 19ft, EV` or `19ft, 22ft, EV` (EV = 0)

Comment: It does work indeed. The downside here is that the `EV` value is hardcoded. Currently, there are only two values in the database with no numbers; your solution works, but the hard code is not a good practice

Comment: @AntonS. I've added info to avoid hardcode. You can define array with no numbers values and use it in your query

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new field to the order

```sql
vehicle_sizes.size = 0, vehicle_sizes.size DESC
```

Or

```sql
vehicle_sizes.size <> 0, vehicle_sizes.size DESC
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. If I do something like `.order('vehicle_sizes.size <> 0, vehicle_sizes.size DESC')` it will throw an error that `<>` doesn't exist. Am I getting it wrong? `size` is a `string` in my case

Comment: What about `.order('vehicle_sizes.size <> "0", vehicle_sizes.size DESC')`